# Meaning of requeues of tc command

Tags: linux, tc, command

I ran this `tc` bellow and it outputs **requeues** with high number, do you know what this requeues means? By the way, it keeps increasing over the time.

I look at `man tc` but I couldn't find anything.

```
$ tc -s qdisc ls dev em1
 qdisc mq 0: root
 Sent 1760345587651 bytes 1790125037 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 **requeues 135812** ) 
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p **requeues 135812**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the count the number of times a packet has been dequeued but not transmitted for some reason and is inserted back at the same position.

If you're interested in the kernel source code: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/A/ident/dev_requeue_skb. You can follow the logic and find exactly under what circumstances a requeue happens.